# write a lib file to add correlation_guid with every json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, overriding

Whenever I render `json` or publish it to some queue I want to attach a correlation_guid so I could follow it along my stack of services that use and push the data along.

The correlation_guid will either be given as a header, or not exist, in which case I'd make it.

Both of these parts are easy. The tough part is actually sticking it in my responses. I was thinking of altering the method `to_json`, so that whenever that method is called, it does something of the following:

```
#should override other to_jsons
def to_json
  unless self[:correlation_id]
    self[:correlation_id] = header['CORRELATION-ID'] || SecureRandom.uuid
  end

  super
end
```

However, how would I catch all the `to_jsons`? I know Array, Hash, ActiveRecord, and probably more have that. Further, I'm pretty sure `super` as above wouldn't work, but the idea is to then use the `to_json` of whatever the original object is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to override the `as_json` in your base model instead. `as_json` is invoked by `to_json`:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb, line 15
def to_json(options = nil)
  ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(self, options)
end

# File activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb, line 48
def encode(value, use_options = true)
  check_for_circular_references(value) do
    jsonified = use_options ? value.as_json(options_for(value)) : value.as_json
    jsonified.encode_json(self)
  end
end
```

Here's also a nice article about the difference between `as_json` and `to_json`: http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/